# laravel 5.4 : Method [mergeRules] does not exist.

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

i've used to chain my validations rules using `mergeRules`

```
$validation = \Validator::make($request->all(), $myrules_1 );
if ($validation->fails())
exit("error1");

$validation->mergeRules($myrules_2);
if($validation->fails())
exit("error2");
```

but after upgrading to 5.4 i get this error

```
BadMethodCallException in Validator.php line 1096:
 Method [mergeRules] does not exist.
```

what happen ? i found this referencing this problem but i cant figure out what the answer is !

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/17646

Comment: Have you tried `addRules()`, I think the method has been changed to addRules(), you may confirm here https://github.com/almeidafranci/framework/blob/2073aeb49def2fdb1d0b2115ec32777336445c5c/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php#L739

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`addRules`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php#L753) instead.

```
/**
 * Parse the given rules and merge them into current rules.
 *
 * @param  array  $rules
 * @return void
 */
public function addRules($rules)
```